# Joint Life Mortality (Qx) - Actuarial

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, actuarial-science

I've a question regarding the calculation of joint life mortality probabilities based on a "last survivor" principle, i.e. both borrowers need to be dead for the event to be triggered.

If I have Qx tables for 2 borrowers (representing the probability each borrower will die aged x exact), I figure the way of calculating the probability that both borrowers are dead will be as follows:

(1) Calculate the survival probabilities for each borrower. Performed using (1-Qx at that point in time) multiplied by the value preceding it, i.e. chaining these probabilities together
(2) Calculate the probability of borrower 1 already being dead (1 - survival probability at that point) multiplied by the probability that borrower 2 dies in that period (simply the Qx value)
(3) The reverse of (2), i.e. probability borrower 2 is already dead multiplied by probability borrower 1 dies in that period
(4) Calculate the probability both borrowers die in that period - calculated as the Qx values for each, multiplied together

Finally, sum together (2), (3) and (4).

The issue with this is, the probabilities will add to 3 (given that each individual probability eventually hits 1) which doesn't make sense, the overall probability must be 1.

Could someone help address this question?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Oliver. I'm attempting to calculate the probability that, at any given point in time, both borrowers are dead. So if we assume we have 2 survival functions, S(A) and S(B), I guess what I'm trying to work out is (1 - S(A)) * (1 - S(B)). The deaths could occur at different times - borrower 1 could die at time 10, whilst borrower 2 could die at time 20, or they could both die at time 20, either would trigger the event

Comment: Yep independence is an assumption, i.e. the mortality of individual A shouldn't impact the mortality of individual B

Comment: Thanks Oliver. So I guess I'm trying to calculate 1 - P[max(T(A), T(b) > t], i.e. 1 - (S(A)(t) - S(B)(t) - S(A)(t)S(B)(t)). The issue with that formula however, is that, after a few periods, this will be higher than the Q(A)(t) or Q(B)(t). I wouldn't have though that this should ever be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two individuals: A and B. Let $T_A$ and $T_B$ denote the time of death of individual $A$ and $B$ respectively measure from say, today. $T^*=T_A\wedge T_B:=\max(T_A,T_B)$ denotes the time at *group* compose by $A$ and $B$ dies (both become death).

Let $S_A(t)=P[T_A>t]$ be the survival function of $A$; similar definition for $T_B$. Under the assumption that the "lives" $A$ and $B$ are independent one gets:

$$\begin{align}
P[T^*>t]&=P[\max(T_A,T_B)>t]=P[T_A>t]+P[T_B>t]-P[\{T_A>t\}\cap\{T_B>t\}]\\
&=P[T_A>t]+P[T_B>t]-P[T_A>t]\,P[T_B>t]\\
&= S_A(t)+S_B(t)-S_A(t)S_B(t)\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}$$

The next step now is to write expressions form $S_A$ (and $S_B$) in terms of the values  one usually sees in actuarial tables: $l_x$, $d_x$, $p_x$,  $q_x$. For simplicity, suppose $A$ and $B$ have ages $a$ and $b$ and that their survival can be obtained from a common actuarial table (they live in the same country, have similar jobs, etc) Using the number of lives $l_x$ we can se $\{l_x:a\leq x\leq \omega\}$ and $\{l_y: b\leq y\leq \omega\}$ to build $S_A$ and $S_B$ respectively, and from these, you can build $S^*(t)=P[T^*>t]$ using the expression \eqref{one}.

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I'm not completely clear on how to get back to $q_x$ from T*. If $q_x$ is defined as $d_x$ / $l_x$, or put another way, ($l_x+1$ - $l_x$) / $l_x$, we'd first have to calculate $l_x$. How do we arrive at that from T*?

Comment: Ah ok - I think I have it now. So $l*_x$ = $S*_x$. Which means $q_x$ = ($S*_x$ - S*_x+1$) / $S*_x$, correct?

Comment: yes, just as you do it for *regular* actuarial tables: $q^*_x = 1-\frac{l^*_{x+1}}{l^*_x}$

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much! I've accepted the answer - is there anything else I can do to thank you for the help? This is my first stackexchange post!

Comment: Hello! I have the same question, but I am a programmer, not a mathematician, so I don't understand the terminology used in the answer. By any chance have you implemented the solution in code or an Excel spreadsheet that you can share? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @mattstuehler:  Similarly from a life of age say $x=30$. Then to create the *last survival* table for the pair of ages 25 and 30, I implement the formula $l^*_x:=\frac{l_{x+25}}{l_{25}}+\frac{l_{x+30}}{l_{30}} -\frac{l_{x+25}}{l_{25}}\frac{l_{x+30}}{l_{30}}$ for $x=0,1,\ldots,100-\max(30,25)$

Comment: @mattstuehler: to create the other fields: $d^*_x=l^*x-l^*_{x+1}$; $q^*_x=\frac{d^*_x}{l^*_x}$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thank you for your help! So I understand... the input to the table is $m_x$, which the mortality rate at age x. For a single life, $l_0 = 100000$, and $l_x =  l_{x-1}(1 - m_{x-1})$. So, now $l_x$ contains the number of people still alive after x years. But, what does the value in column $l_x^*$ "represent" or mean?

Comment: @OliverDiaz By the way, what I'm really after is how to calculate the **life expectancy** of a married couple using this approach. I've asked my actual question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4169990/calculate-joint-and-last-survivor-life-expectancy-actuarial. I'd be grateful for any guidance you have there!

Comment: In the context of the problem, $l^*_x$ plays the role of $l_x$ but not for a a single infividual, for for the "entity" composed of two individuals ages $25$, $30$ in my example. Expectancy may be found by a crude trapezoidal method: $\frac12(l^*_0+2(l^*_1+\ldots + l^*_{100-\max{a,b}-1})+l^*_{100-\max{a, b}})$

Comment: If I understand you correctly...
$$l_0^* = \frac{l_{25}}{l_{25}}+\frac{l_{30}}{l_{30}}-\frac{l_{25}}{l_{25}}\frac{l_{30}}{l_{30}}$$
$$l_1^* = \frac{l_{26}}{l_{25}}+\frac{l_{31}}{l_{30}}-\frac{l_{26}}{l_{25}}\frac{l_{31}}{l_{30}}$$
$$l_2^* = \frac{l_{27}}{l_{25}}+\frac{l_{32}}{l_{30}}-\frac{l_{27}}{l_{25}}\frac{l_{32}}{l_{30}}$$
...etc.
So, won't all the $l_x^*$ values be < 1?

Comment: I forgot to "normalize" so that $l^*_0=100000$, just multiply the right-hand-side of your equations by $100000$, I missed the factor.

Comment: @mattstuehler: if this is not clear yet, let me know. then I'll make an edit to may answer later today with a construction.