# Calculate joint and last survivor life expectancy - actuarial

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I've been able to figure out how a basic life table works.

But I would like to know how to extend it to calculate the life expectancy of the last survivor of a married couple.

(I understand there are some complexities from the fact that deaths of married couples may not be independent, but I can ignore that here...)

With a simple life table, you have a column of values named **$m_x$**, which represent the mortality rate at age x. (I'm using unisex mortality rates, so I don't need to worry about the sex of the person.)

You also have a column of values named **$l_x$**, which is the number of persons alive at age x (where $l_0$ starts at 100,000). So, $$l_x = l_{x-1}(1 - m_{x-1})$$

**$d_x$** contains the number of persons who died in the interval (x, x+1), which is $l_xm_x$

**$L_x$** contains the total number of person-years lived by the cohort in the interval (x, x+1), which is the equal to $l_{x+1} + 0.5d_x$. (Each person who lives to x+1 contributes one year, and each person who dies in x contributes half a year, on average.)

**$T_x$** contains the total number of person-years lived by the cohort from age x until all members of the cohort have died. I.e., the sum of $L_x$ through $L_n$ (where n is the total number of rows).

Finally, **$e_x$** contains the life expectancy of a person at age x, computed as $e_x = \frac{T_x}{l_x}$.

This all makes sense to me.

But, how would I use this approach to calculate the "joint and survivor" life expectancy of two people (e.g., a married couple) assuming their deaths are independent? I.e., how long would you expect *at least one of those two people to still be alive?*

A few simplifications for my specfic question...

1. I'm using a single **unisex** mortality rate, so I don't need to worry about the sex of each person.
2. I can assume the deaths are independent
3. I can assume that **both people are the same age**

Comment: Hi matt. You should use our MathJax typesetting system for your mathematical expressions. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164/

Comment: This is not actuarial science.